# Excel Macro causes file to re-open

Tags: excel, vba

I have an odd issue with a macro I put together for work.

Backstory, I basically designed a macro to close a protected-workbooks after being left opened after X amount of time. its a shared document, and when people open it, they often forget to close the document, locking it up so others can't use it.

So I took bits and pieces of other macros to create a timer.

```
Sub Start_Timer()
'BASIC UP COUNTER
Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "CheckStatus"
End Sub


Sub CheckStatus()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets

If ws.Range("IV1").Value > 60 Then
'IF IDLE LONGER THAN VALUE ABOVE, RUN THE FOLLOWING
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'WORKS TO DISABLE ALERT PROMPT
ThisWorkbook.Close (False) 'CLOSE FILE WITHOUT SAVING
Application.Quit
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'RESETS DISPLAY ALERTS
End Sub    

Else
'ADD 1 TO COUNTER
ws.Range("IV1").Value = ws.Range("IV1").Value + 1
End If
Next
Start_Timer
End Sub
```

in ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet
MsgBox ("This Worksheet has a 15 min timer")

Start_Timer
For Each ws In Worksheets
'Columns("IV:IV").Hidden = True

ws.Range("IV1").Value = 1
Next
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
ts.Range("IV1").Value = 1
Next
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'WORKS TO DISABLE ALERT PROMPT
ThisWorkbook.Close (False) 'CLOSE FILE WITHOUT SAVING
Application.Quit
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'RESETS DISPLAY ALERTS
End Sub
```

For the most part it works. But, I'd rather eliminate the like "Application.Quit". The problem I am having is that when I eliminate that line, the Workbook instantly re-opens after closing it manually, or trying to quit excel manually.

I assume it might have to do with constantly changing the value of 1 cell (far off so no one sees it) and exiting without saving.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Anyone know how to check what happens after i close a file?
I try breakpoints, but they are get erased after the file is closed, so I dont know what happens after it closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a global variable to store the last scheduled OnTime() time value and adjust your timer sub:

```
Dim lastTimer As Variant

Sub Start_Timer()
    'BASIC UP COUNTER
    lastTimer = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime lastTimer, "CheckStatus"
End Sub
```

Then add this to the Workbook_BeforeClose event:

```
Application.OnTime lastTimer, "CheckStatus", , False
```

This will cancel the last scheduled call by Application.OnTime().

Comment: you are right, that is what the problem is.
I made many edits (the code you gave me didnt work the way i hoped), so I added sub functions, but at the end, it was the "Application.OnTime lastTimer, "CheckStatus", , False" that fixed the problem. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a typo?:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ts In Worksheets
         ^ws ??
If ws.Range("IV1").Value > 60 Then
```

Comment: Always use `Option Explicit` to avoid typo's as indicated by qPCR4vir

Comment: oh thats my bad. That typo was me changing it for stackoverflow so it made more sense. On the actual file, they are the same. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You know you can give an Excel file a shared status, so that it can be accessed simultaniously by multiple users?

see for example:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/share-a-workbook-HP005202595.aspx

Comment: Yes, we had a long discussion about this, and they want to leave it this way. What ended up happening was someone opened the file and went home for the weekend. 

So after many arguments, and me laying out all the options, this is what they wanted.
I work in IT, fun stuff!

Comment: and then the business has an Excel as CRM? Oh joy and happiness for you!

Comment: Its the fun of work, they want to do it backwards, you just gotta make it happen!